# ace register_handler fails

Tags: c++, ace

I am using ace register_handler function in a system with multiple threads.
Every once in a while, register_handler fails. I printed the file descriptor (by calling get_handle function) and I noticed the when the file descriptor is above 1000, get_handle fails.
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an ACE expert. But it seems that the default implementation in the ACE_Event_Handler class does return an error, everytime. Extract from the ACE source code:

```
ACE_HANDLE
ACE_Event_Handler::get_handle (void) const
{
  ACE_TRACE ("ACE_Event_Handler::get_handle");
  return ACE_INVALID_HANDLE;
}
```

Derived class needs to implement their own. Therefore if your class derives from the class ACE_Event_Handler you must override the `get_handle()` method in order to have a meaningful result:

```
ACE_HANDLE DerivedClass::get_handle(void) const
{
  return peer().get_handle();
}
```

I would recommend you to

1. Verify you are providing that method in your derived class.
2. If so, double check its implementation. Our issue is in here. (May you provide us more details on your implementation ?)
3. If you didn't provide any override, then you know you must implement it.

Comment: I found out that regitor_handle fails because i have to much file descriptor opened. Is there any way I can increase the number of file descriptor ace supports without recompiling ace?

Comment: I think it is an Operation System issue. Which OS are you using? Win32 ? Linux ?

Comment: Linux. I see the limitation is 1024 but i want to increase it

Comment: There is two kind of limit. Soft and Hard. Soft limit is managed by your shell, and modifying it depend on your shell. For instance for bash you need to invoke: ulumit -n 2048 to set the new limit at 2048. The file /etc/security/limits.conf will allow you to modify the hard limit. Of course the Soft limit cannot exceed the Hard one.

Comment: I think you'll have a more complete answer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/165316/how-to-configure-linux-file-descriptor-limit-with-fs-file-max-and-ulimit

Comment: I changed it but it didnt help. I see a limitation in ace which I want to increase. I found that reactor->open file receives the maximum number of file descriptors. I tried changing it but it didnt work too.

Comment: Are you sure you did change *every* limit ? Hard & Soft ?